# Como deixar um formulário do Delphi semi-transparente?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4, object-pascal

Olá, para ficar mais simples de entender veja o exemplo da imagem abaixo, dês de já agradeço por ter lido minha pergunta![image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Galera eu dei uma olhada neste mesmo site só que na versão em inglês e achei a solução, [clique aqui para ver.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17897182/labels-speedbuttons-not-showing-in-glass-frame-delphi-xe4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faça o seguinte:

1. Mude para *true* o valor da propriedade `AlphaBend` do formulário.
2. Na propriedade `AlphaBlendValue` você altera o nível de transparência, o padrão é *255*. 
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

   Resultado:

   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dependendo da versão que você estiver usando, é possível fazer este efeito habilitando as propriedades `Enabled` e `SheetOfGlass` do `GlassFrame` para *true*.
 [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Isto afetaria todo o formulário, encontrei outra forma!

Comment: @PascalStarting Sim, eu estava atualizando a resposta com algo sobre isso.